# Merge several time-series datasets into one

Tags: kotlin, time-series

Given several sets of time-stamped data, how can one merge them into one?

Suppose, I have a dataset represented by the following data structure (Kotlin):

```
data class Data(
  val ax: Double?, 
  val ay: Double?, 
  val az: Double?, 
  val timestamp: Long
)
```

ax, ay, az - accelerations over the respective axes

timestamp - unix timestamp

Now, I got three datasets: Ax, Ay, Az. Each dataset has two non-null fields: the timestamp and the acceleration over its' own axis.

```
Ax:
+-----+------+------+-----------+
| ax  |  ay  |  az  | timestamp |
+-----+------+------+-----------+
| 0.0 | null | null |         0 |
| 0.1 | null | null |        50 |
| 0.2 | null | null |       100 |
+-----+------+------+-----------+

Ay:
+------+-----+------+-----------+
|  ax  | ay  |  az  | timestamp |
+------+-----+------+-----------+
| null | 1.0 | null |        10 |
| null | 1.1 | null |        20 |
| null | 1.2 | null |        30 |
+------+-----+------+-----------+

Az:
+------+------+-----+-----------+
|  ax  |  ay  | az  | timestamp |
+------+------+-----+-----------+
| null | null | 2.0 |        20 |
| null | null | 2.1 |        40 |
| null | null | 2.2 |        60 |
+------+------+-----+-----------+
```

What the algorithm would produce is:

```
+------+------+------+-----------+
| ax   |  ay  |  az  | timestamp |
+------+------+------+-----------+    
| 0.0  | null | null |         0 |
| 0.0  | 1.0  | null |        10 |
| 0.0  | 1.1  | 2.0  |        20 |
| 0.0  | 1.2  | 2.0  |        30 |
| 0.0  | 1.2  | 2.1  |        40 |
| 0.1  | 1.2  | 2.1  |        50 |
| 0.1  | 1.2  | 2.2  |        60 |
| 0.2  | 1.2  | 2.2  |       100 |
+------+------+------+-----------+
```

So in order to merge three datasets into one, I:

- Put Ax, Ay and Az into one list:

  ```
  val united: List<Data> = arrayListOf<Data>()
  united.addAll(Ax)
  united.addAll(Ay)
  united.addAll(Az)
  ```
- Sort the resulting list by timestamp:

  ```
  united.sortBy { it.timestamp }
  ```
- Copy unchanged values down the stream:

  ```
  var tempAx: Double? = null
  var tempAy: Double? = null
  var tempAz: Double? = null

  for (i in 1 until united.size) {
      val curr = united[i]
      val prev = united[i-1]

      if (curr.ax == null) {
          if (prev.ax != null) {
              curr.ax = prev.ax
              tempAx = prev.ax
          }
          else curr.ax = tempAx
      }

      if (curr.ay == null) {
          if (prev.ay != null) {
              curr.ay = prev.ay
              tempAy = prev.ay
          }
          else curr.ay = tempAy
      }

      if (curr.az == null) {
          if (prev.az != null) {
              curr.az = prev.az
              tempAz = prev.az
          }
          else curr.az = tempAz
      }
  }
  ```
- Remove duplicated rows (with the same timestamp):

  ```
  return united.distinctBy { it.timestamp }
  ```

The above method could be improved by merging two lists at a time, I could perhaps create a function for that.
Is there a more elegant solution to this problem? Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: This question would be just as appropriate (or even more) at [StackExchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `Data` rather contains `var`s instead of `val`s (otherwise your code wouldn't work). The following is a rewrite of your function using grouped timestamps and a method, that either extracts the interested property or returns the last known value for the given property otherwise.

```
// your tempdata containing the default (starting) values:
val tempData = Data(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0L)

fun extract(dataList: List<Data>, prop: KMutableProperty1<Data, Double?>) = 
   // find the first non null value for the given property
   dataList.firstOrNull { prop(it) != null }
           // extract that property
           ?.let(prop)
           // set the extracted value in our tempData so that it can reused if a null value is retrieved in future
           ?.also { prop.set(tempData, it) }
           // if the above didn't return a value, use the last one set into tempData
           ?: prop(tempData)

val mergedData = /* your united.addAll */ (Ax + Ay + Az)
             .groupBy { it.timestamp }
             // your sort by timestamp
             .toSortedMap()
             .map {(timestamp, dataList) ->
                 Data(extract(dataList, Data::ax),
                         extract(dataList, Data::ay),
                         extract(dataList, Data::az),
                         timestamp
                 )
```

It's rather hard to come up with a better approach as your main condition (defaulting to the last resolved value) will actually force you to have your dataset sorted and to hold a (or several) temporary variable(s).

However, the benefits of this version in contrast to yours are the following:

- don't bother about the indices
- less duplicated code
- no need to remove any duplicates from the returned list (no need to `distinctBy`)
- while the `extract`-method itself might be complex, the usage of it is more readable

Maybe by refactoring the `extract` the whole gets more readable too.

As you also said, that you want it to be easily portable to Java, here a possible Java rewrite:

```
Map<Long, List<Data>> unitedList = Stream.concat(Stream.concat(Ax.stream(), Ay.stream()), Az.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getTimestamp));

List<Data> mergedData = unitedList.keySet().stream().sorted()
            .map(key -> {
                List<Data> dataList = unitedList.get(key);
                return new Data(extract(dataList, Data::getAx, Data::setAx),
                        extract(dataList, Data::getAy, Data::setAy),
                        extract(dataList, Data::getAz, Data::setAz),
                        key);
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and the `extract` could then look like:

```
Double extract(List<Data> dataList, Function<Data, Double> getter, BiConsumer<Data, Double> setter) {
    Optional<Double> relevantProperty = dataList.stream()
            .map(getter)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .findFirst();
    if (relevantProperty.isPresent()) {
        setter.accept(tempData, relevantProperty.get());
        return relevantProperty.get();
    } else {
        return getter.apply(tempData);
    }
}
```

Basically the same mechanism.

Comment: The problem is that the data arrives at different frequencies. So I need to know what were the actual values of each characteristic at each moment in time for further analysis (machine learning, etc.) I chose to store every signal in the same data object. But I could have come up with a more general one like``RawData(val value: Double?, val timestamp: Long)`` Your zip option is not relevant for such a task. As for your remark on the null values I could have returned: ``united.distinctBy { it.timestamp }.filter {it.ax != null && it.ay != null && it.az != null}``

Comment: adapted the answer... the general idea of using the `groupBy` remains the same. Instead of your three `var`s I just used a single `Data`-object. Note that you do not have to use the `Data::ax`,etc. but I didn't like the idea to repeat the same code again and again.

Comment: For now it's just a rewrite of what you currently have ... You have many conditions that need to be satisified... There isn't so much room to improve your solution then... You at least can eliminate all the duplication

Comment: That requirement changes everything. But the general idea remains the same. I would still group it first (in Java 8 via stream) and then remap it.

Comment: I can see you are using reflection. That's the only limitation of your solution. Personally I like it as it removes a lot of duplicated code. Why do you transform List to Iterable (``Ax.asIterable()``), though? Isn't a List already an Iterable?

Comment: Regarding the `asIterable` you are right... don't know why I used it... you can omit it... regarding reflection I would just use method references in Java instead... You just need a `Function<Data, Double>` for the getter and a `BiConsumer<Data, Double>` for the setter (so you actually pass two instead of 1 method reference, e.g. `extract(dataList, Data::getAx, Data::setAx)`).

Comment: Updated the answer with a Java snippet and regarding reflection: you do not need to use it... you can also just pass a getting and a setting function... see the Java pendant as reference.

Answer (score 0):

So at the moment I am using this solution:

```
data class Data(
        var ax: Double?,
        var ay: Double?,
        var az: Double?,
        val timestamp: Long
)

fun mergeDatasets(Ax: List<Data>, Ay: List<Data>, Az: List<Data>): List<Data> {
    val united = mutableListOf<Data>()
    united.addAll(Ax)
    united.addAll(Ay)
    united.addAll(Az)

    united.sortBy { it.timestamp }

    var tempAx: Double? = null
    var tempAy: Double? = null
    var tempAz: Double? = null

    for (i in 1 until united.size) {
        val curr = united[i]
        val prev = united[i-1]

        if (curr.ax == null) {
            if (prev.ax != null) {
                curr.ax = prev.ax
                tempAx = prev.ax
            }
            else curr.ax = tempAx
        }

        if (curr.ay == null) {
            if (prev.ay != null) {
                curr.ay = prev.ay
                tempAy = prev.ay
            }
            else curr.ay = tempAy
        }

        if (curr.az == null) {
            if (prev.az != null) {
                curr.az = prev.az
                tempAz = prev.az
            }
            else curr.az = tempAz
        }

        if (curr.timestamp == prev.timestamp) {
            prev.ax = curr.ax
            prev.ay = curr.ay
            prev.az = curr.az
        }
    }

    return united.distinctBy { it.timestamp }
}
```